# Complex combination of Allow and Deny for Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

With Apache, I searched to deny access to all *.php URL in a subdirectory. I succeed with this in .htaccess:

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from All

<Files ~ "^.*\.php$">
    Deny from All
</Files>
```

But now, I want to add a extra access for one single URL who was denied. I made a lot of test but a obtained only no effect or "error 500" for example with this :

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from All

<Directory "/home/site/www/repertoire1/repertoire2/">
    <Files "fichier.php">
        Allow from All
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Files ~ "^.*\.php$">
    Deny from All
</Files>
```

this .htaccess is in "repertoire1" and the URL I want to allow is http://example.com/repertoire1/repertoire2/fichier.php

I cannot put files in the directory "repertoire2" then I want to put all access rules in one single .htaccess file

Comment: more than 2 years ago, I am always wondering if it's possible to do that with Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `<Directory>` in .htaccess, context is server config or virtual host: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#directory

You have to set another .htaccess in /home/site/www/repertoire1/repertoire2/ with

```
<Files "fichier.php">
    Allow from All
</Files>
```

in it

Comment: as I said in my question, i cannot put a file in "repertoire2"